# Laravel 5.2 form validation not showing errors?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

My form validation is not showing any error

My routes.php file is as follows:

```
Route::post('/user/add/form', [
    'uses' => 'AdminController@adduser',
    'as' => 'admin.add.user.to.database' 
    ]);
```

My adduser function in AdminController contains following:

```
$this->validate($request,[
        'email'=> 'required|email',
        'name'=> 'required',
        'password'=> 'required',
        'aright'=> 'required',
        'dob' => 'date',
        'publication'=> 'string',
        'utype' => 'required'
]);
```

This is the blade view which I am using for form. This asks for some of the fields whihc are shown in controller function and should show the error if the required field are not filled but it is not showing anything.

```
@extends('layouts.admin-master')

@section('styles')
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap /3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
@endsection

@section('scripts')
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var token = "{{ Session::token() }}";
</script>
@endsection
@section('content')
@include('includes.info')
@if(count($errors) > 0)


        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
            <h1> {!! $error->first() !!} </h1>
        @endforeach

@endif
<div class="container">
    <h2>Add User Form</h2>
<form  class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ route('admin.add.user.to.database') }}">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email" value="{{ Request::old('email') }}">
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="name">Name:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">          
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name" name="name">
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">    
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">          
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="password">
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group"> 
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2"  for="aright">Access Type:</label>
                    <select class="col-sm-10" id="aright" name="aright">
                        <option value="2">Normal Member</option>
                        <option value="1">Admin</option>
                    </select>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="publication">Publication:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="publication" placeholder="Enter publication link" name="publication">
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="dob">Date of birth:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">          
                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="dob" placeholder="Enter DOB" name="dob">
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group"> 
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2"  for="utype">User Type:</label>
                    <select class="col-sm-10" id="aright" name="utype">
                        <option value="2">Faculty</option>
                        <option value="1">Student</option>
                    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-center">        
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
     <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
</form>

</div>

@endsection
```

Comment: Post the code in your view please

Comment: Update your question by providing additional information

Comment: In routes did you use 'web' middleware? This sets the Session.

Comment: yes, i already did that.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? >= 5.2.27?

Comment: yes I am using Laravel 5.2.29

Comment: Yeah this solved the problem. Thanks. It was a recent update which caused the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of v5.2.27, released on 2015-03-25, all routes in app\Http\routes.php are now in the web middleware group by default. If you have explicitly specified this middleware group inside your app\Http\routes.php file, you need to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is that you are calling first() on the error? first() is a method on the MessageBag instance ie $errors. See the problem line

```
<h1> {!! $error->first() !!} </h1>
```

Change to

```
<h1> {{ $error }} </h1>
```

Comment: did this change. still having the same problem